# Modal will not open from href link

Tags: html, css

I have followed a detailed instruction from https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/ on creating a modal.

I have done everything to plan but when I go to click the modal in the navBar arrow link, it opens stating that #openModal cannot be found.

Attached is my HTML and CSS code:

```css
body { /* General Body Properties */
    font-family: Trebuchet MS, Georgia, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

* { /* Key element to aligning <divs> (DO NOT REMOVE) */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#wrapper {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0
}

.header { /* Header properties featuring myEd and school emblems */
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center; /* Aligns links in the navBar */
    background-image: url(/Default/Img/backgroundHeader-4K.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.myEd-reverse {
    width: 240px;
    height: 70px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -60px;
    margin-top: -40px;
}

.navBar { /* Sticky navBar, either relative or fixed, depending on the scroll position of the site */
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.navBar a { /* Style the navBar links */
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navBar a.right { /* Float Quick Links, Help and Log-out navBar directory items to the right of the navBar */
    float: right;
}

.navBar a:hover { /* Change color on hover */
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: #000;
}

.navBar a.active { /* Active Link */
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
}

.modalDialog {
 position: fixed;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 z-index: 99999;
 opacity:0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
 opacity:1;
 pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
 width: 400px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 10% auto;
 padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: #fff;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.close {
 background: #606061;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 line-height: 25px;
 position: absolute;
 right: -12px;
 text-align: center;
 top: -10px;
 width: 24px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
 -moz-border-radius: 12px;
 border-radius: 12px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }

.row { /* Alignment between sideBar and main */
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.sideBar { /* sideBar alignment properties */
    -ms-flex: 20%;
    flex: 20%;
    background-color: #a7a7a7;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 5000px; /* As standard to work on all screen resolutions, overflow hides excess */
    overflow-y: scroll; /* Allows myEd news to scroll */
    overflow: hidden;
}

#newsmyEd {
    width: 100%;
    height: 11.4%;
    min-height: 11.4%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.main { /* Main Column */
    -ms-flex: 80%;
    flex: 80%;
    background-color: #a7a7a7;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 5000px; /* As standard to work on all screen resolutions, overflow hides excess */
    overflow-y: scroll; /* Allows embedded iFrame to scroll */
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.frameMain { /* Frame Properties */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 0;
    min-height: 11.4%;
}

.footer { /* Footer properties */
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #333;
}

.footer a { /* Footer navBar properties */
    float: right;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.footer a:hover { /* Change color on hover */
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: #000;
}

.footer a.active { /* Active Link */
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
} 

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) { /* Responsive Layout - If screen px is less than 700px, make sideBar and main stack on top of each other */
    .row {   
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) { /* Responsive Layout - If screen px is less than 400px, make navBar links stack vertically on top of each other */
    .navBar a {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Home/Welcome/Style/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Default/Img/faviconmyEd-16x16.png">

<script>
 // Required scripts for certain activities on myEd, each entry will be noted for understanding
</script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- Wrapper fitting website to all screen resolutions -->
    <div class="header">
        <!-- Header featuring 4K Background, myEd and school emblems -->
        <img src="/Default/Img/myEd-reverse.png" class="myEd-reverse" alt="myEd" title="myEd Software"> <!-- myEd Software -->
    </div>
    <div class="navBar">
        <!-- Main sticky navBar with categories listed -->
        <a href="#" class="active" title="Home Workspace"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a> <!-- Home -->
        <a href="#" title="Learning Workspace"><i class="fa fa-book"></i></a> <!-- Learning -->
        <a href="#" title="Student Management Workspace"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a> <!-- Student Management -->
        <a href="#" title="Portal Workspace"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a> <!-- Portals -->
        <a href="#" class="right" title="Log-out"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></a> <!-- Log-out (right to left) -->
        <a href="#" class="right" title="Help"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></a> <!-- Help (right to left) -->
        <a href="#" class="right" title="Quick Links"><i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i></a> <!-- Quick Links (right to left) -->
        <a href="openModal" class="right" title="Profile Overview"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a> <!-- Profile dropDown (right to left) -->
        <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
            <div>
                <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
                <h2>Modal Box</h2>
                <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
                <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Format for alignment of the sideBar and main panels -->
        <div class="main">
            <!-- Main learning or collaborative workspace -->
            <iframe class="frameMain" width="100%" height="11.4%" scrolling="yes" src="/Home/Welcome/iFrame/index.html"></iframe> <!-- Embedded frame -->
        </div>
        <div class="sideBar">
            <!-- sideBar featuring Profile, myEd News and directory -->
            <iframe id="newsmyEd" frameborder="0" src="/Default/News/index.html"></iframe> <!-- myEd News -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <!-- Featuring Site Navigation and myEd News navBar links -->
        <a href="#" class="active" title="myEd News"><i class="far fa-newspaper"></i></a> <!-- myEd News -->
        <a href="/Home/Welcome/siteNavigation/index.html" title="Site Navigation"><i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i></a> <!-- Site Navigation -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="#openModal" class="right" title="Profile Overview">
     <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
</a>
```

You forgot to put '#'

Comment: It works but it highlights the main section and the modal cannot be seen.

Comment: The problem is in your `.main` selector. Remove `position: relative` unless it's needed but that's what blocking the modal

Comment: position: relative is needed as it keeps the layout and allows for the frameMain to remain positioned nicely. Would there be an alternate way around it?

Comment: Since `.main` has a `position: relative`, I added `z-index: -1` to it to have it placed underneath the modal dialog. Hope this would solve your problem

Comment: Bro your a lifesaver! Thanks for your help!

Comment: The modal works great however now the .frameMain section is not clickable, I believe it's due to the z-index = -1, anyway we can fix that up so the modal and main iFrame work?

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="openModal" class="right" title="Profile Overview"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
```

should be

```
<a href="#openModal" `class="right" title="Profile Overview"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>`
```

Comment: It works but it highlights the main section and the modal cannot be seen.